# Display Wordpress Post on A Different Site

Tags: php, rss

I'm looking for a way to show the latest post from my wordpress site on another site that isn't a wordpress site.

Also the display of the post I want to style to include the featured thumbnail, the category, and the title in the manner below.

[image]

I can do the css/html for it but the problem is I don't know where or how to start this process.

So far my search results tell me how to do it from one wordpress site to another, but I need to do it from one wordpress site to a none wordpress site.

Any idea as to how I can do this process?

Comment: have you looked at wordpress rss feed and api?

Answer (score 2):

**TBH** I think its a bit late to answer this question, But here it goes anyways.

All you need to do is format some JSON Data

Step 1:

Get the JSON

> domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=1&_embed&taxonomy

Change `per_page=1` to the number of posts you'd like to query

If you want to filter the post according to tags or categories

You can find more Query tags on:
http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/tags/

Step 2:

> Format the **JSON** keep what you need forget the rest

### Examples

**Post Title & URL**

[image]

**Post Featured Image** *(It automatically gives you a link for thumbnails too)*

[image]

**Post Tags & Categories**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have the wp-rest api to get posts from another site.

You may have a look to `wp_get_remote_post()` and `wp_remote_retrieve_body()` to get the remote post content in your own loop.

Note: wp rest api must be active in both server. I.e [Wp rest api v2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/)

Depending on which WordPress version your site is running, you'll maybe need to modify the response, to include the feature image link.

You can easily create a shortcode to display it where you want in your template.

Comment: This answer expects both of the sites to be wordpress sites, which the question author told not to be the case.